# ranking in linq based on group by condition?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to rank on list by Linq.

```
class test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  Destination { get; set; }
}
```

my data is as follows:

```
ID          Destination
1           Miami
2           Miami
3           Boston
4           Atlanta
```

what i want is this:

```
ID          Destination        Value
1           Miami              Miami1
2           Miami              Miami2
3           Boston             Boston1
4           Atlanta            Atlanta1
```

How to get this by Linq??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
list.GroupBy(l => l.Destination)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select((x,i) => new {
                                            x.Id, 
                                            x.Destination,  
                                            Value = x.Destination + (i+1)
                                           }));
```

The `i` in the `SelectMany` will give you the index of the item in each group.  Just add 1 to get the rank.

Results:

```
Id destination   Value 
1  Miami         Miami1 
2  Miami         Miami2 
3  Boston        Boston1 
4  Atlanta       Atlanta1
```

Comment: nice, you miss the last `)`?

Comment: thanks Stanley. is it possible to do without group by, just want know

Comment: Sure, but why?  There's probably a dozen different ways to do it.  You could also just iterate directly in a `foreach` loop but it wouldn't be as clean.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could compute the ranks within groups:

```
var result =
    items.GroupBy(d => d.destination)
            .SelectMany(g =>
                        g.Select(d =>
                                new
                                    {
                                        d.Id,
                                        d.destination,
                                        Value = d.destination +
                                                (g.Count(x => x.Id < d.Id) + 1)
                                    }));
```

Comment: This is way more work than is needed, given that [select gives you the index if you ask for it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18190654/1159478).

Comment: @Servy yes, if the assumption that items are ordered by `id` is correct, `(x, i) => ...` works fine

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x=>x.Destination)
                 .Select(g => g.Select((x,i) => 
                                   new {
                                        ID = x.ID,
                                        Destination = x.Destination,
                                        Value = x.Destination + (i + 1)                                             
                                       }))
                 .SelectMany(x=>x);
```